# Spring Boot and Hibernate Envers: Manually updating AUD-Table

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-envers

I would like to manually update records of an AUD-table which get generated and populated by Hibernate Envers within the same transaction.
Sadly I found no JPA- or Envers-event which I can listen to, that I'm right before a JPA transaction is commited but AUD-tables are already populated.

Do you know how I can do this?

I'm using Spring Boot 2.0.2, Hibernate 5.2.17, Envers 5.2.16

---

### Edit (Solution with Interceptor)

It is possible to extend from `org.hibernate.EmptyInterceptor` and override the method `beforeTransactionCompletion`. In `application.properties` of Spring Boot you have to register the custom interceptor with

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.ejb.interceptor=com.example.CustomInterceptor
```

Disadvantage: You lose your connection to the audited entities. In this method you only get the hibernate transaction to play with.

---

### Edit II (Solution with AuditStrategy)

Extend `org.hibernate.envers.strategy.DefaultAuditStrategy`, override the `perform`-method and modify the `data`-Array. This array is not bound to JPA, so it is possible to insert additional data in columns which are unknown to JPA.

Register your custom AuditStrategy in application.properties

```
spring.jpa.properties.org.hibernate.envers.audit_strategy=com.example.CustomAuditStrategy
```

Comment: That is not something which we support.  The idea is that your audit tables are suppose to be mirrors of the entity state at a given point in time and allowing user code to manipulate and alter that invalidates that premise.  Perhaps if you could clarify what you're trying to accomplish there might be a better way to do it that is supported.

Comment: I found a solution. Please see updated question.

Comment: Sure there are lots of ways to inject into the process, but before recommending something I wanted to understand the purpose.  e.g. is it because if only certain state was being modified you wanted to veto or prevent a field from being audited?  These are things that are supported but are supported via other means.  Manipulating the audit data in the wrong place could lead to inconsistencies that, while it may work for recording the audit entry, may cause long-term problems while querying it if done incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is fixed since Hibernate Version 5.4.0. Now AuditStrategies are more flexible and modular.

See: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-13051